# Detecting if client has any kind of PDF reader installed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a naive detection of whether a PDF reader is installed on a given webpage; if it is, I will allow the installed reader to view the pdf in an iframe, if not I use an embedded google viewer.

I'm not necessarily interested in a 100% fool proof solution, but something that will catch the vast majority of users. When I do detect a pdf reader is installed, I do want to be absolutely certain.  If you have something weird installed, you probably already know how to download the actual pdf if you want.

I'm assuming I want to determine which browser the user is viewing. Once I have that are there any cheap shortcuts or assumptions I can use?

I know I can do this for IE, but what about for Firefox or Chrome?:

```
   var installed;

   try
   {
    installed = new ActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF');
   }
   catch (e){}

   if (!installed)
   {
    try
    {
     // Older Ie
     isntalled = new ActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
    }
    catch (e) {}
   }

   return installed;
```

Comment: Chrome has a build in generic reader in it so it might come down to just firefox for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps http://downloads.beninzambia.com/blog/acrobat_detection.js.txt?

Comment: Does firefox just use `navigator.plugins['Adobe Acrobat'];` then?  From that code, which is helpful btw, I don't see where firefox is handled.